# Anyone knows JQuery plugin to produce tree menu look like on geni.com

Tags: jquery, menu, tree

Hello Everyone
                 I am wandering from hours to locate a Jquery plugin to produce a tree menu module like on geni.com , if anyone know such a plugin or script in Jquery kindly let me know or guide me how i can develop such functionality using Jquery?

Please check what i am looking for http://www.geni.com/family-tree/index/6000000010663773201
its developed in Flash but i wanna create same thing in Jquery.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This family tree by Pawnesh maybe what you need.
[image]
https://github.com/pawnesh/family_tree

Another option is GoJS family tree

[image]
[gojs family tree](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/familyTree.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is no complete plugin for this. I used to work for a genealogy company so I know. You either have to start developing your own based on receiving JSON data regarding the relationship between family nodes, placements etc. Which is a very nice experience but will take you about 3 to 4 months solid at least.

Or you can start by [Google Visualisation API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/examples.html#querywrapper). This link points you directly to an example of the API being used for a family tree type scenario. Although still you will need to add the drag to it.

I would say have a chat with your work people. And tell them about your options. If you are a front end guy there and you want to have this service as part of a business I would seriously consider making a bespoke one as it will teach you a lot and you can then improve it according to business and customer needs. If its not that important then knock one off the visualisation API and see you will get on.

Also I don't want to say Names, but do a Google search on Genealogy companies. SOME are out there who are using JavaScript successfully for this and you might be able to inspect some source code and get inspiration from them.

Also check The [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/), which provides tools for creating Interactive Data Visualizations for the Web.

Comment: did you find any alternative for the same?